# Driving from Kuala Lumpur to Singapore for someone who is not a Malaysian or Singaporean citizen

Tags: driving, singapore, malaysia

I am considering, at some point in the future, driving from Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia to Singapore. Assume I am not a citizen of Malaysia or Singapore and will receive a 14 day tourist visa upon land entry.

Is this possible? If so, how would I reasonably go about doing this?

Driving from Kuala Lumpur to Johor Baru and then finding alternate means (bus, taxi) onto Singapore is acceptable. I suspect the requirements to drive in Singapore are much more stringent then driving in Malaysia. Please recommend the means to get from Johor Baru to Singapore if I can only drive to Johor Baru.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, unless you really need your car in Singapore, there's no need to drive, or even go via Johor Bahru: there are lots of cheap flights, buses and even a train from KL direct to Singapore.  See [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Singapore#Get%20in) for the full scoop.

But assuming you insist, and you're driving a West Malaysian-registered vehicle, the Land Transport Authority has a [handy guide](http://www.lta.gov.sg/content/ltaweb/en/roads-and-motoring/driving-in-and-out-of-singapore/west-malaysian-registered-vehicles-and-cars-and-motorcycles.html) for you.  Quick summary:

> Before entering Singapore, please ensure that you have:
>
> - valid insurance coverage for your vehicle for the duration of your    vehicle’s stay in Singapore
> - valid road tax for your vehicle
> - an Autopass Card with sufficient value
> - an In-Vehicle Unit (IU) – either install a permanent one at IU Service Centres or rent one at Tuas/Woodlands Checkpoints – if your
>     vehicle needs to pass through priced roads during Electronic Road
>     Pricing (ERP) hours

You can buy the AutoPass on entry (S$10) and the IU rental costs $5/day.  The nationality of the driver or passengers makes no difference, although obviously you need to have visas etc if needed.